# Biblatex/biber Citation, one citation author is getting full name, no just last name et al

Tags: biblatex

I have a document with about 600 references I'm working on.  I have biblatex setup in the following manner.

```
%   Bibliography stuff
%
    %   \usepackage{biblatex}
    \usepackage[style=authoryear,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=1,uniquelist=false,backend=biber,dashed=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{ThesisRefs.bib}

    % Make the citations have square brackets instead of round brackets
    \AtEveryCite{%
        \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
        \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
        \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}
```

For nearly ALL of my references, I get something that looks like

```
Smith et al. 2018
```

Which is what I want.  But, there are two or so references, that come in as a citation that includes the first name, looking like

```
Jeff Johnson et al. 2018
```

I've looked at my .bib file, and there is nothing different between the files.  I even tried renamed 'Jeff' to 'Dave' in the bib file.  And then the citations look like

```
'D. Johnson et al. 2018'
```

If I delete all my document text.  Keep the SAME preamble.  And write in just one or two lines of dummy text and \parencite{Johnson2018}, it comes in correctly.  It only messes up when I have all many hundreds of references included with the full document.

I've tried making a MWE, but it only 'breaks' when I have the entire document.

How do I force ALL references to ONLY use the 'last' or 'family' name?

Comment: What happens if you cite, say, two 2018 Johnsons in a minimal document?

Comment: That looks very much like disambiguation of the name Johnson. Which means you probably have some other Johnson in your references, and biblatex distinguishes them by adding other name parts. If you don't want that to happen, you should use the option `uniquename=false`. But, once you already have that in your options, along with `uniquelist=false`, I'd say we probably would have to be able to reproduce the problem somehow to be able to find the culprit. That is, we would have to see a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: @cfr If I cite two same or two different Johnsons in the minimal document it works fine. I get Johnson et al.

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, I already have uniquelist and uniquename to be false.  Which is why I'm surprised I still get first names included. I thought those commands should make it ignore first names.  ....Which, it does for all the others. I have MANY other references with same last names, and they all went to just LastName et al. Its just like two or three references that don't do it.  And I cant figure out how they are different from the others. I was hoping someone knew of some bug/workaround

Comment: As far as I know this behavior is controlled by these two options. These options are also settable on a per-entry basis, which means they may be overridden by your entries options. But I doubt we will be able to help unless you show us some code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Post the problematic `.bib` entries? Maybe somebody will spot something. Also look in the `.log` and `.blg` files for anything relevant and see if you can spot differences in the `.bbl`.

Comment: The behaviour you describe definitely looks as though `uniquename` is not actually properly disabled. Do you have other settings for the bibliography that you have not shown us? Add `\makeatletter\blx@uniquename\makeatletter` to the very first page of your document and tell me what number you see (0, 1 or 2?). What version of `biblatex` and Biber do you have?

Comment: I am not aware of any bugs with `uniquename` at the moment, so I would be *really* interested to see an MWE that reproduces the issues you get. Start with a new document, cite all sources with `\nocite{*}` and cite a few (or all) Johnsons explicitly with `\cite`. Does that reproduce the issue?

Comment: Any news here?.

Comment: @gusbrs Yeah, I was able to look at this again this afternoon. And now it works. I honestly don't think I changed anything, but I must have had something wrong.  Sorry I wasted peoples time.  Should I delete the question?

Comment: Thank you for reporting back. And there is no reason for apologies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.